# Why we say Happy New Year without an article "a", but we say "I wish you a Happy New Year" using the article?

Tags: word-usage, articles

I was wondering if there is any rule in English that forbids us to say A Happy New Year when we wish someone Happy New Year? I know that we just say it like that, but I was trying to find the rule which would explain this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I also say "Good Morning", not "A Good Morning". So there's obviously consistency there.

Answer (score 2):

When I say "Happy New Year", it isn't a complete sentence, grammatical rules do not exactly apply to it. It is just a phrase that we use to wish each other. If you want to use the complete wish, you can use "May you have a happy new year" or "I wish you a happy new year".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And what about this case: When we say Happy New Year and a prosperous 2016? We use a before prosperous 2016, but we still don't put a before Happy New Year? Is that correct?

Comment: Same case here. While this is an acceptable sentence, it is not correct as per English grammar.